# NoReverseMatch at Django tamplate url

Tags: django, url, django-template

Пытаюсь прописать URL в шаблоне Django

urls.py

```
 path('<slug:region_slug>/<slug:channel_slug>', ChannelTodayView.as_view(), name='channel_today_url')
```

html

```
<a href="{% url 'channel_today_url' %}">Текст ссылки</a>
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

> NoReverseMatch at /tv-program/spb
> Reverse for 'channel_today_url' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tv\-program/(?P<region_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<channel_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить (видимо, ему надо как-то передать region_slug и channel_slug)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте требуемые параметры для формирования url

```
{% url 'channel_today_url' "region_slug" "slug:channel_slug" %}
```